# how to get from gallery and update in recyclerview at particular position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm unable to update individual image in recyclerview fetching from gallery through intent.

Here is my code remove images from recyclerview is working but update image to particular position is tricky.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class ImagesAdaper extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdaper.ImagesViewHolder>  {

    ArrayList<ImagesPojo> list=new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public ImagesAdaper(ArrayList<ImagesPojo> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.imagesitem,parent,false);
        return new ImagesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImagesViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        ImagesPojo imagesPojo=list.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageURI(imagesPojo.getUri());

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             list.remove(position);
             notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RoundedImageView imageView;
        ImageView delete,edit;

        public ImagesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImages);
            delete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteitem);
            edit=itemView.findViewById(R.id.edititem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something like notifyitemchanged(). Just for one item. What did you try? And what is it that is tricky?